# what is wheel, when i try install some python packages?

Tags: python

Guys Although i have seen some other errors that are similar to my problem, but i still cant solve this, i just want to install (timezonefinder) that does not look like a heavy module,
but when i try:

```
python -m pip install timefinderzone
```

the result will be:

```
 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h3
Failed to build h3
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h3, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

ill be happy if you can give me an efficient way to solve this, thanks.

Comment: Which version of python and pip are you using, could you please update in the questions.

Comment: Is the package you are trying to install `timezonefinder`?

Comment: Is there a more complete error message above what you show us…?

Answer (score 0):

The [wheel](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Wheel) is an installer for the package. Sometimes installing from the wheel (through `pip`) helps solve some installation issues.

[In the package's page](https://pypi.org/project/timezonefinder/#files) you can download the wheel (*whl* file) that corresponds to your Python version and system architecture. You can learn more about it [here](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/python-install-wheel/).

I would suggest you check the package is available for your system, your architecture and your Python version.

Comment: and where can i put the downloaded file?

Comment: Anywhere, just navigate to the folder where you put it or give `pip` the complete path to it

Comment: and here is the result >>> ERROR: timezonefinder-6.1.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_31_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: What that is telling you is that either you are not using Python 3.8 or your system architecture is not x64 or both. Also I'm not completely sure but that wheel may only be for Linux distros (`manylinux` hint in file name)